# Stacked Bar Chart with percentage composition inside the Bar and total above the Bar in JFreeChart

Tags: customization, jfreechart, bar-chart, stacked

I am trying to create a Stacked Bar Chart. My requirement is I need percentage composition inside the bar and total count on top of the Bar.   Please suggest solutions.

My Requirement:
Sample : http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/images/StackedBarRenderer3DSample.png

I want percentage composition inside the bar and total composition on the top of the bar.

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you are doing now, but using a [`StackedBarRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/StackedBarRenderer.html) with `setRenderAsPercentages(true)` will display the percentages. To get the total, extend [`StackedBarRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/StackedBarRenderer.html), loop through the dataset for each column, and override `drawItem()` to draw the result. An example may be found in the [*JFreeChart Demo*](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jnlp) as part of `StackedBarChartDemo3`.

As an alternative, consider a custom [`CategoryToolTipGenerator`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/CategoryToolTipGenerator.html), added via `setBaseToolTipGenerator()`.

Addendum: You linked to an example using [`StackedBarRenderer3D`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/StackedBarRenderer3D.html), which also has a `setRenderAsPercentages()` method. It can be extended similarly.

Comment: Cheers mate, it worked. I extended the StackedBarRenderer and added a CategoryToolTipGenerator to it. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem too. For some reason the latest version of JFreeChart does not display the percentage composition inside the bar. Here's how I got it to work:

```
    StackedBarRenderer br = new StackedBarRenderer(true); //enable perc. display
    br.setBarPainter(new StandardBarPainter());
    br.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator());
    br.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
    chart.getCategoryPlot().setRenderer(br);
```

Hope this helps