# Barchart Percentage in jfreechart

Tags: jfreechart

i want percentage symbol after the values in barchart using jfreechart already tried lot but didn't get proper result.
In jfreechart they given percentage for barchart3ddemo. 
I want normal barchart demo example program percentage symbol please help me out..

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757287/stacked-bar-chart-with-percentage-composition-inside-the-bar-and-total-above-the

Comment: For more specific help, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use your chosen renderer's `setSeriesItemLabelsVisible()` or `setBaseItemLabelsVisible()` method to show the labels. If necessary, you can supply your own `CategoryItemLabelGenerator`, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8117844/230513).